# Set Position of Graph View

Tags: android, xml, android-graphview

1-) I've been trying to implement a `GraphView` in my application. It works and compiles fine and when I run the application it is  shown in the screen.  My problem is that I can't move my `GraphView` anywhere.  I want to move it to  bottom a little bit but it won't move.  I tried to do it manually from XML however, nothing changes.

2-)In addition to that my XML design page is not previewed properly.  So I can't set the position of the `GraphView` from XML Design section.  When I try to change the position it automatically adds  `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY` and `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX`.  I know that `tools:layout` are not compiled.  So, I don't know why I can't preview graph properly because it does not give me any error either.

I have added a picture of my emulator.

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this.Thanks a lot.

My Main Class Code

```
public class Main3 extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);



    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[]{
            new DataPoint(0, 2),
            new DataPoint(1,3),
            new DataPoint(2,3),

    });
    graph.addSeries(series);

}
}
```

My XML

```
  <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
     />
```

Comment: layout_height and layout_width on your RelativeLayout  should be match_parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the layout like this the graph appears in the middle vertically. I believe your problem lies in `android:layout_height="match_parent"` of RelativeLayout. For future reference please post all of the relevant code to allow for proper diagnostics.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:id="@+id/graph"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```